# App isn't verified Google Fit SDK with right SHA1

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-fit-sdk

I'm using **Google App Signing** for my app that integrates the Google Fit SDK (so OAuth).
I've already added the `SHA1` fingerprint of Google signing certificate in my Firebase Project Settings and updated my `google-services.json` in app. Still, when I choose my Google Account, the app (published on the store) show a screen saying "*App is not verified by Google....*". How can I fix this? Is it a matter of time/update? Many thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the error message then.  where are you seeing the App is not verified by Google... if not on the consent screen.   If your accessing Google Fit data then you have to be authorized to access the users account you must have a consent screen.